# Mini css extract plugin de Webpack no exporta

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, gulp

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un archivo de configuración de Webpack  en el que he implementado el plugin "mini-css-extract-pliguin" como pueden ver aquí:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
return {
    entry: './src/js/main.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'bundle'),

    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
                //use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                use: ["file-loader"],
            }
        ],
    },

    plugins:
        [
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({

                title: 'proyecto-webpack',
                template: "./src/index.html"
            }),


        ],
    }
};
```

Y tengo un archivo de CSS muy simple:

```
body{
 background: red;
}

header{
 text-align: center;
 background-image: url("../img/black-cat.jpg");
}
```

Cuando hago mi npm run build, me da el siguiente error la consola:

> ```
> ERROR in ./src/css/main.css Module build failed (from
> >> ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
> ```

He probado al eliminar la propiedad y en ese caso si me exporta correctamente pero quiero sustituya en la propiedad del CSS la URL.

¿Alguien a tenido algún problema parecido?

Comment: @Israel-ICM gracias por la edición y disculpa. Son las prisas aunque no hay excusa, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando webpack 5 ?
Por lo que he probado te da error por la importacion de la umagen.
Tuve el mismo problema y lo que hice fue agregar las propiedades type y generator
aqui:

```
test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
type: 'asset/resource',
generator: { filename: './images/[name].[contenthash][ext]' }
```

Yo genere el archivo css dentro de la carpeta css, y las imágenes se guardan en la carpeta images en la raíz,
despues modifique la regla de scss y css a lo siguiente:

```
{
test: /\.(c|sc|sa)ss$/,
use: [
      {
         loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
         options: {publicPath: path.relative(__dirname, '../', 'images')},
      },
      'css-loader',
      'sass-loader',
     ]
}
```

En tu caso el plublicPath qudaria

```
publicPath:  path.relative(__dirname, ' ')
```

Aqui hay informacion sobre esto : type: 'asset/resource' y generator
https://dev.to/smelukov/webpack-5-asset-modules-2o3h